# memory leak under GCC (but not Clang) when throwing in the middle of a C++14 initializer list for std::list<shared_ptr>

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, shared-ptr, initializer-list

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){
        if (s_ct==0) {throw std::bad_alloc();}
        --s_ct;
        fprintf(stderr, "ctor %p\n", this);
    }
    ~Foo(){
        fprintf(stderr, "dtor %p\n", this);
    }
private:
    static int s_ct;
};

int Foo::s_ct = 2;

int main(){
    try {
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> l = {
            std::make_shared<Foo>(),
            std::make_shared<Foo>(),
            std::make_shared<Foo>()
        };
    } catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
        fprintf(stderr, "caught exception.\n");
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
[little:~] $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR     PURPOSE.

[little:~] $ g++ --std=c++14 -o list_init list_init.cc
[little:~] $
```

The output is:

```
[little:~] $ ./list_init 
ctor 0x1294c30
ctor 0x1294c50
caught exception.
done.
[little:~] $
```

Notice that the destructors are not called.  Valgrind correctly complains of the leak as well.

This seems to violate one of the key purposes of `std::make_shared` -- namely, that if another expression in the statement throws, the shared object gets properly destroyed because it is wrapped by a fully constructed shared pointer object.

Clang does what I would like here:

```
[little:~] $ clang++ --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
[little:~] $ clang++ --std=c++14 -o foo list_init.cc
[little:~] $ ./foo
ctor 0x1dfec30
ctor 0x1dfec50
dtor 0x1dfec50
dtor 0x1dfec30
caught exception.
done.
[little:~] $
```

So is this a GCC bug, or do I need to fix my program?

Comment: Looks like a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2015-05/msg01091.html): *"destructor not called for members of partially constructed anonymous struct/array"*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer so you can mark the question as answered.*

This looks to be a gcc bug

> [Bug 66139](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66139) - **destructor not called for members of partially constructed anonymous struct/array**

Note in particular the last two test cases which use `std::initializer_list` to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Is it something different from partial objects (created if exception is thrown from constructor) and destructor will not be called later